# C++ and Microsoft SAPI 5: How to list all available voices and select a voice

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, java-native-interface, sapi

First of all, C++ is not my language (I'm a java programmer).

I've seen examples of Microsoft SAPI 5.1, and I need a way to print all the available voices in a machine. I've seen the [Object token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of SAPI, and I'm kinda confuse of how CComPtr is use to iterate through. Can anyone help me with this. Additionally, how can I pick a specific voice instead of using the default.

Based from the examples, you can get the default voice by invoking this codes:

```
ISpVoice * pVoice = NULL;

if (FAILED(::CoInitialize(NULL)))
    return FALSE;

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void **)&pVoice);
```

So in short: **How can I list all the voices available and how can I choose the voice?**

//PS: I **don't** need to put it in a combo box (just like all examples that I've seen), I'm implementing this for a JNI dll library so an example of iteration is much preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, CComPtr is a smart pointer abstraction over COM interfaces, not an enumerator.

To list all the voices, you need to enumerate the tokens in the [SPCAT_VOICES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms937496.aspx) category.

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
CComPtr<ISpObjectTokenCategory> cpSpCategory = NULL; 
if (SUCCEEDED(hr = SpGetCategoryFromId(SPCAT_VOICES, &cpSpCategory))) 
{ 
    CComPtr<IEnumSpObjectTokens> cpSpEnumTokens; 
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr = cpSpCategory->EnumTokens(NULL, NULL, &cpSpEnumTokens))) 
   { 
        CComPtr<ISpObjectToken> pSpTok;
        while (SUCCEEDED(hr = cpSpEnumTokens->Next(1,&pSpTok, NULL)))) 
        {
            // do something with the token here; for example, set the voice
            pVoice->SetVoice(pSpTok,FALSE); 
            // NOTE:  IEnumSpObjectTokens::Next will *overwrite* the pointer; must manually release
            pSpTok.Release(); 
        }
   } 
}
```

If you want to pick a specific voice, you need to specify an attribute that's unique to that voice.  [EnumTokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms718145%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) allows you to specify required and optional attributes.  The attributes are actually defined by the creator of the voice, but some common attributes are

- Name (e.g., "Microsoft Anna")
- Language (specified by a numeric locale ID)
- Gender (male/female)
- Vendor (name of company that created the voice)

So to specify "Microsoft Anna" instead of any voice, you would use

```
if (SUCCEEDED(hr = cpSpCategory->EnumTokens(L"Name=Microsoft Anna", NULL, &cpSpEnumTokens)))
```

instead of

```
if (SUCCEEDED(hr = cpSpCategory->EnumTokens(NULL, NULL, &cpSpEnumTokens)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)
Btw, the inner while loop runs infinitely.
I think we can use the GetCount method to keep count of no tokens, so that we know when to stop. I am sure, you would be aware of other methods.

Comment: the call to get language returns an MS LangID, it needs to be converted to a BCP 47 language tag (eg. en-GB). How do we do it ?

Comment: @YashGirdhar Try [LCIDToLocaleName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318698(v=vs.85).aspx).  This would be a good question, incidentally....

Comment: Thanks for the link .But I am not able to achieve it. Say, it returns "809", now how do I convert it into LCID first, as LCIDHex for English is "0809", and LCIDec is "2057".

Comment: You need to open a separate question for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337602/how-to-convert-sapis-ms-lang-id-to-bcp-47-language-tag

Answer (score 0):

The enum method does work but is a little clunky. The best way is to open the registry and go through the keys and their attributes, you can find more information here:

[msdn: SAPI Tokens, Categories and the Registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717036(v=vs.85).aspx)

Again that's a bit of work, so I've created an interface while doing something else and it may help you or somebody else:

[Sapi interface for enumerating and searching voice tokens](https://github.com/clu-at-tron-dot-rocks/clutts)